# Websocket call timeout on Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm using websockets for the first time and am unsure what I am doing wrong.  Due to my IP being dynamic, I am using the following websocket call serverside:

```
$echo = new echoServer("myurl.com","9000");
```

and the following call clientside:

```
socket = new WebSocket("wss://myurl.com:9000");
```

I get a timeout err even though the server is completely unoccupied.  Does anyone know why?I feel this is a basic error

Comment: might need `http://myurl.com`, or to use an IP # instead of a host name.

Comment: My first instinct is to look at any firewall issues.

Comment: @dandavis, the `wss://` protocol is correct in this case.  It's for opening a secure WebSockets connection, similar to `https://`.

Comment: Also, are you getting any errors when starting up your WebSockets server?

Comment: @Ghedipunk: client part's fine, its the backend that needs an outside address, and "myurl.com" is not a URI

Comment: @dandavis -- Yep, I should have noticed that.  In this case, they want `new echoServer('0.0.0.0', '9000')`, because the server side IP is the _listening_ IP address.  0.0.0.0 means to listen on all IPs that can route a message to that machine.  I suspect there are still issues, though, so I'm waiting for clarification on what errors they seen when starting the WS server, though.

Comment: Also would be useful for clarification: OP: Which WebSockets server are you running?  That looks like it's probably PHP-Websockets.  (I really need to come up with a clever name for it... :P )

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'm using PHP websockets, as you guessed.  The server actually starts up fine, no issue.  The issue arises when I try to connect to serverside via clientside, always "Websocket is closed before the connection is established."  On the threads it seems like a general error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific server, [PHP-Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets), does not provide support for the `wss://` protocol (secure connection, similar to `https://` for HTTP traffic).

Change the connection line to:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://myurl.com:9000");
```

Alternatively, if you need TLS support, PHP-Websockets might not be the best server for you.

I made the decision to not support TLS in PHP-Websockets because I did not know of any robustly tested, battle hardened PHP packages that provide access to the OpenSSL libraries.  I have changed my mind as of 5 minutes ago, and will implement TLS using the built in PHP OpenSSL functions, but this will take time to implement and will require several testers.  If you don't want to wait, don't wait.

I do not want people to think that their data is secure when I simply can't guarantee it.

---

Also, not specifically causing a failure but still an issue: In your server-side code, you should change instantiating the server's object to:

```
$echo = new echoServer("0.0.0.0", "9000");
```

The reason is that the IP address is setting the server's listen address.  The listen address of "0.0.0.0" gets translated to "listen on all IP addresses that this machine can listen to."  That means that, besides just your own public IP, it will also listen to 127.0.0.1, and if you have a second network card that has a different IP address assigned to it, you can receive traffic from that as well.

However, because of PHP's weak typing, when `socket_bind()` attempts to convert the IP address into its binary representation, but finds a string instead, it silently converts it to 0, which is equivalent to the IP address 0.0.0.0.

(I previously thought that `socket_bind()` was performing a DNS lookup to get the IP address.  I was very wrong.  Such weak typing on the part of PHP, and especially the assumptions made by developers like me, is the cause of many security holes.)

Comment: Thanks.  That's pretty huge, the part about wss support.  I may use a rudimentary RSA encryption manually for my own communications then.  I'll be following whatever progress you post.

Comment: @user3216649 use stunnel